# strsplit one column with exact information into two column

Tags: r, split

I have data looking like this:

```
    SNP Geno Allele
marker1   G1    AA
marker2   G1    TT
marker3   G1    TT
marker1   G2    CC
marker2   G2    AA
marker3   G2    TT
marker1   G3    GG
marker2   G3    AA
marker3   G3    TT
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
    SNP Geno Allele1 Allele2
marker1   G1       A       A
marker2   G1       T       T
marker3   G1       T       T
marker1   G2       C       C
marker2   G2       A       A
marker3   G2       T       T
marker1   G3       G       G
marker2   G3       A       A
marker3   G3       T       T
```

I am using this:

```
strsplit(Allele, split extended = TRUE)
```

But this is not working. Do I need additional commands?

Comment: @Chase - removing or updating dead link would be nice. especially when downvoting.

Comment: Updating a two+ year old link...see [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/reshape2/docs/colsplit) for references on the `colsplit` function from package `reshape2`.

Comment: @topchef - updated the two year old link...internet has a funny history sometimes...thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another approach, from start to finish:

Make reproducible data:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE,  text = "SNP Geno    Allele
marker1 G1  AA
marker2 G1  TT
marker3 G1  TT
marker1 G2  CC
marker2 G2  AA
marker3 G2  TT
marker1 G3  GG
marker2 G3  AA
marker3 G3  TT")
```

**UPDATED** Extract the Allele column, split it into individual characters, then make those characters into two columns of a data frame:

**EITHER**

```
dat1 <- data.frame(t(matrix(
                     unlist(strsplit(as.vector(dat$Allele), split = "")), 
                     ncol = length(dat$Allele), nrow = 2)))
```

**OR** following @joran's suggestion

```
dat1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(dat$Allele), split = "")))
```

**THEN**

Add column names to the new columns:

```
names(dat1) <- c("Allele1", "Allele2")
```

Attach the two new columns to columns from the original data table, as @user1317221 suggests:

```
dat3 <- cbind(dat$SNP, dat$Geno, dat1)
        dat$SNP dat$Geno Allele1 Allele2
1 marker1       G1       A       A
2 marker2       G1       T       T
3 marker3       G1       T       T
4 marker1       G2       C       C
5 marker2       G2       A       A
6 marker3       G2       T       T
7 marker1       G3       G       G
8 marker2       G3       A       A
9 marker3       G3       T       T
```

Comment: I tried your code, the shape of the data is how I wanted it, but the letters for allele 1 and allele 2 are not right. Somehow R is not splitting the column correctly. For the 2nd row it should be an A for allele 1 and allele 2, instead it is a A and T and that is wrong.

Comment: I think you probably wanted to do something like `do.call(rbind,...)` on the results of the `strsplit` call.

Comment: @marie, sorry about that, my mistake. I've updated the answer now, the output now matches what the you want exactly.

Comment: @joran thanks for that, I'm not very familiar with `do.call`, but it works as you say and saves quite a bit of typing!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Allele<-dat$Allele    
Allele1<-substr(Allele, start = 1, stop = 1)
Allele2<-substr(Allele, start = 2, stop = 2)
```

you can then cbind them together or however you want to put them in the data frame

EDIT:

@Ben is correct I have corrected my code for you above or use Ben's suggestion

`Allele1 <- with(dat, substr(Allele, start = 1, stop = 1))`

Comment: The column reference is incomplete in your answer, you should have something like `Allele1 <- with(dat, substr(Allele, start = 1, stop = 1))` or `Allele1 <- substr(dat$Allele, start = 1, stop = 1)`

Comment: I tried your code but  the "allele" column is still not separated.

Comment: what errors or results do you get then? do you realise this code makes two new vectors of the format you want, it does not change the actual allele column?

Answer (score 2):

Another trick for this is to use `read.fwf`. Unlike `read.table` and co., `read.fwf` doesn't have a `text` argument, so you need to use `textConnection`:

```
# dat$Allele <- as.character(dat$Allele) # Necessary if it's a factor
cbind(dat[-3], 
      read.fwf(textConnection(dat$Allele), 
               widths = c(1, 1), col.names=c("Allele1", "Allele2")))
#       SNP Geno Allele1 Allele2
# 1 marker1   G1       A       A
# 2 marker2   G1       T       T
# 3 marker3   G1       T       T
# 4 marker1   G2       C       C
# 5 marker2   G2       A       A
# 6 marker3   G2       T       T
# 7 marker1   G3       G       G
# 8 marker2   G3       A       A
# 9 marker3   G3       T       T
```

---

***Old answer***

Building on both alternatives already presented, here's a one-line version (assuming your data frame is named `dat`.

```
transform(dat, Allele1 = substr(Allele, 1, 1), 
          Allele2 = substr(Allele, 2, 2))[-3]
```

Which gives us:

```
      SNP Geno Allele1 Allele2
1 marker1   G1       A       A
2 marker2   G1       T       T
3 marker3   G1       T       T
4 marker1   G2       C       C
5 marker2   G2       A       A
6 marker3   G2       T       T
7 marker1   G3       G       G
8 marker2   G3       A       A
9 marker3   G3       T       T
```

It's exactly the same concept as [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421936/1270695) but using `transform`.

---

#### Update (a long time later)

You can also use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package with the argument `stripWhite = FALSE`.

For example, to split the "Allele" column, try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dat, "Allele", "", stripWhite = FALSE)
#        SNP Geno Allele_1 Allele_2
# 1: marker1   G1        A        A
# 2: marker2   G1        T        T
# 3: marker3   G1        T        T
# 4: marker1   G2        C        C
# 5: marker2   G2        A        A
# 6: marker3   G2        T        T
# 7: marker1   G3        G        G
# 8: marker2   G3        A        A
# 9: marker3   G3        T        T
```

See also: [Split one column to two columns in R with looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312597/split-one-column-to-two-columns-in-r-with-looping)