# Split one column to two columns in R with looping

Tags: r, split

Actually I have same problem with this case [strsplit one column with exact information into two column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421668/strsplit-one-column-with-exact-information-into-two-column)

That question already solved, just my data is just looks like

```
      SNP Geno AlleleA AlleleB AlleleC AlleleD AlleleE
1 marker1   G1      AA      AA      AA      AA      AA
2 marker2   G1      TT      TT      TT      TT      TT
3 marker3   G1      TT      TT      TT      TT      TT
4 marker1   G2      CC      CC      CC      CC      CC
5 marker2   G2      AA      AA      AA      AA      AA
6 marker3   G2      TT      TT      TT      TT      TT
7 marker1   G3      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG
8 marker2   G3      AA      AA      AA      AA      AA
9 marker3   G3      TT      TT      TT      TT      TT
```

dput output:

```
structure(list(SNP = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("marker1", "marker2", "marker3"), class = "factor"), 
    Geno = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("G1", 
    "G2", "G3"), class = "factor"), AlleleA = structure(c(1L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("AA", "CC", "GG", 
    "TT"), class = "factor"), AlleleB = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("AA", 
    "CC", "GG", "TT")), AlleleC = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("AA", "CC", 
    "GG", "TT")), AlleleD = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("AA", "CC", "GG", 
    "TT")), AlleleE = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("AA", "CC", "GG", "TT"
    ))), .Names = c("SNP", "Geno", "AlleleA", "AlleleB", "AlleleC", 
"AlleleD", "AlleleE"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

On that question he just has one columns that want to split to two columns. The problem is I have 5000 columns (AlleleA, AlleleB.........etc) that want to split (each one column to two columns)

I've tried to use looping like this but it doesnt work,

```
for(i in colnames(dat)){
  dat1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(sprintf("dat$%s",i)), split = "")))
}
```

I will wait your light, 
thank you

Comment: How do you want to split the columns? (each column in exactly two columns and how is the split defined?). In tidyr there's a `separate` function which splits a column into multiple columns and you might be able to apply this to each column you want to split using for example dplyr's `mutate_each` function..

Comment: @beginneR I've modified my question

Comment: @beginneR its works use splitstackshape :) thank to Ananda Mahto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package with the argument `stripWhite = FALSE`.

For example, if we wanted to split all the "Allele*" columns, we would do:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydf, grep("Allele", names(mydf)), "", stripWhite = FALSE)
#        SNP Geno AlleleA_1 AlleleA_2 AlleleB_1 AlleleB_2 AlleleC_1
# 1: marker1   G1         A         A         A         A         A
# 2: marker2   G1         T         T         T         T         T
# 3: marker3   G1         T         T         T         T         T
# 4: marker1   G2         C         C         C         C         C
# 5: marker2   G2         A         A         A         A         A
# 6: marker3   G2         T         T         T         T         T
# 7: marker1   G3         G         G         G         G         G
# 8: marker2   G3         A         A         A         A         A
# 9: marker3   G3         T         T         T         T         T
#    AlleleC_2 AlleleD_1 AlleleD_2 AlleleE_1 AlleleE_2
# 1:         A         A         A         A         A
# 2:         T         T         T         T         T
# 3:         T         T         T         T         T
# 4:         C         C         C         C         C
# 5:         A         A         A         A         A
# 6:         T         T         T         T         T
# 7:         G         G         G         G         G
# 8:         A         A         A         A         A
# 9:         T         T         T         T         T
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
library(qdap)
res <- colsplit2df(dat, splitcols=2:ncol(dat),sep='')
colnames(res)[-1] <- make.names(rep(colnames(dat)[-1],each=2), unique=TRUE)
res[1:3,1:5]
#      SNP Geno Geno.1 AlleleA AlleleA.1
#1 marker1    G      1       A         A
#2 marker2    G      1       T         T
#3 marker3    G      1       T         T
```

Or only for `Allele` columns

```
colsplit2df(dat, splitcols=grep('Allele', names(dat)),sep='')
```

**Edit** (Tyler Rinker)

May I suggest editing the column names of the data.frame using `setNames` first as follows:

```
setNames(dat, gsub("([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+[A-Z])", "\\1.1&\\1.2", names(dat))) %>%
    colsplit2df(splitcols=3:ncol(dat), sep='')
```

Answer (score 2):

As @beginneR says, you can use `tidyr::separate`. Here is an example taken from:http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/

```
head(tidier, 8)

#>   id       trt     key    time
#> 1  1 treatment work.T1 0.08514
#> 2  2   control work.T1 0.22544
#> 3  3 treatment work.T1 0.27453
#> 4  4   control work.T1 0.27231
#> 5  1 treatment home.T1 0.61583
#> 6  2   control home.T1 0.42967
#> 7  3 treatment home.T1 0.65166
#> 8  4   control home.T1 0.56774

tidy <- tidier %>%
  separate(key, into = c("location", "time"), sep = "\\.") 
tidy %>% head(8)
#>   id       trt location time    time
#> 1  1 treatment     work   T1 0.08514
#> 2  2   control     work   T1 0.22544
#> 3  3 treatment     work   T1 0.27453
#> 4  4   control     work   T1 0.27231
#> 5  1 treatment     home   T1 0.61583
#> 6  2   control     home   T1 0.42967
#> 7  3 treatment     home   T1 0.65166
#> 8  4   control     home   T1 0.56774
```

Comment: I *think* the question is more related to having to do such splitting across *multiple* columns.

Comment: you are right, I did not read well the question, nor @beginneR's comment.

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite sure whether this can be done using a combination of `mutate_each` and `separate`, at least not as flexibly as in Ananda's answer, since separate requires you to specify into what columns you want to split each column.